# Is "https://google.com/search?query=sea" RestAPI?

Tags: rest, http

I recently studied RestAPI.
I have question about that If I used get method in a format like [www.google.com/search?query=sea](http://www.google.com/search?query=sea) , and got html as a response value, can I call it restapi?
I think the self-descriptive, hateos of the uniform interface is satisfied because it is in html format. However, I think it violates the identifying resource. Therefore I think this is just http method.
Is it right? please answer. thank you!

Comment: No that is not a REST API.  It is just a web page

Comment: REST is poorly defined, anything can be a REST api depending on who you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the collection of architectural constraints that were used in the standardization of the world wide web during the 1990s.

> I think it violates the identifying resource.

Resource identification falls under the [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) constraint; it just says that we use resource identifiers to... identify resources.

```
https://www.google.com/search?query=sea
```

That right there would be a resource identifier, so you are satisfying that constraint.

---

> can I call it restapi?

Technically?  yes, of course.  You could cite Fielding again

- [Advantages of a Network-based API](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_5_1)
- [Rest APIs must be hypertext-driven](https://web.archive.org/web/20230531205540/https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

But as a matter of communication, if you want to be understood then you need to verify that your audience understands the labels that you are using the same way that you mean them.

See also [Semantic Diffusion](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiffusion.html).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on other parts as well as questions! 
I tried to explain "self-descriptive messages, hypermedia as the engine of application state" about the uniform interface, but it was ambiguous.